# Adding Devices to Samsung SmartThings

Tags: smart-home, wireless, samsung-smartthings

I've got the Samsung SmartThings system installed in my house, but I've encountered a few situations where a new device (e.g. an in-wall outlet) couldn't be found through the SmartThings App on my Android phone. A temporary fix for me was to move one of my plug-in outlets about halfway to serve as a "bridge" between the SmartThings Hub and the new outlet.

My question is if there is an alternate way of adding new objects to my smart home? For instance my phone? Alternatively, what wireless technology (e.g. ZigBee, Z-Wave, Bluetooth) is needed to complete these links?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently Smart things uses  [Z-Wave protocol among others like Philips Hue.](https://www.smartthings.com/works-with-smartthings)

Maybe you should add your devices near the SmartThings hub for it to recognize them to check if they are compatible.

However, be aware of distance, Z-Wave devices tend to always "sleep" and escape the network.

Comment: What about in instances where I'm installing in-wall outlets or switches? It doesn't make much sense to "install" a switch in the room with the hub, sync it, uninstall it, and re-install in the place I originally wanted.

Comment: ZWave devices that sleep will always have a manual way to turn them back on and as long as the device is certified is guaranteed not to "escape the network" as it wouldn't pass cert if it did.

Comment: Indeed in-wall outlets are an exception since they need power to work. I don't have a solution for the SmartThings...

Comment: @Dom Do you know if there is a way to verify that a device is certified? Any sort of stamp or standard note?